# win32_printer not appear in wmiobject (Windows Power Shell)

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an issue on a PC with Windows 7 Professional. I need to list the network printers in my local network, I tried to run the list object classes in PowerShell with the command:

```
Get-WMIObject -List | where {$_.name -match 'win32_printer'}
```

This shows empty, any suggestion to fix this problem?

**EDIT:**
My script for get the network printers is this:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\; get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\view\\data\\printers.json
```

I need to list the printers in a json file, In my PC runs well, but in the PC where i need to run this script fail

Comment: Go read the documentation on `Get-WMIObject`; you want to use the `-class` parameter. Note that there are two relevant classes; one addresses "local" printers (i.e., not serviced by another computer), the other addresses network printers serviced by another computer.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin `Win32_Printer` lists out both local and network printers.

Comment: @BenH - We've had situations where `Win32_Printer` doesn't catch printer connections to network printers; for those, we needed `Win32_PrinterConnection`.

Comment: Yeah, I already read the official documentation, my script for get the printers is something like that: 
`Set-Location -Path C:\; get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\view\\data\\printers.json`

In my PC runs well but in the PC where i need to run this command not works

Comment: @user3738208 - You should edit your question to reflect that, and include the details of how it fails.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: I get this error in power shell:  `invalid class win32_printer`

Comment: There is something wrong with that machine, `Win32_Printer` has been a standard class in `root/cimv2` for a long time. I would start with `Winmgmt /salvagerepository`

Comment: Yes I know, maybe it's a corruption in the respository, I was check the integrity of mvi but it's ok, I dont understand what happen with that PC, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your command list out all WMI classes then filters those classes showing all of them that contain `Win32_Printer`. It seems that you want use:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer
```

This will list all printers that are connected to your computer (Not all of them that are on your network). Note that it will only show network printer connected to your user account.

If you are looking for all printers on your network you could list all of the queues published in Active Directory

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "ObjectCategory -eq 'printQueue'"
```

Note: This command requires the AD module from RSAT